# What are the cats watching?

Tags: black-butler

So I came across the following picture in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/anime-and-manga). What anime are the cats watching?

[image: cats love anime]

Even cats love anime.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The anime the cats are watching is [Black Butler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Butler)

[image]

(Extract from the linked wikipedia page)

> The series follows Ciel Phantomhive, the thirteen-year-old head of the Phantomhive noble family and the business-savvy owner of the Funtom company, a toy manufacturer.
>
> Ciel has formed a demonic contract with Sebastian Michaelis. In return, when Sebastian has helped Ciel finish all of his tasks, including avenging his parents' deaths, Sebastian will be allowed to consume Ciel's soul.
>
> It was announced in July 2008 that an anime adaption, directed by Toshiya Shinohara and produced by A-1 Pictures, was expected.
>
> It premiered in October 2008, and has since ended with 24 episodes. The second season aired in 2010 spanning 12 episodes with two new main characters, Alois Trancy and Claude Faustus.
>
> The series has been licensed by Yen Press in North America and published in Yen Plus' August 2009 issue for the magazine's first anniversary.

Comment: ... Beat me by seconds. Well-played, sir.

Comment: Literally just logged in ^_^

Comment: Nothing "probably" about it. That's clearly Sebastian.

Comment: Oh, and Sebastian *loves* cats.